# What is the set operation corresponds to the last Venn diagram below?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let the universal set be $U$ which is represented as the rectangular frame.
Set $A$, $B$ and $C$ are the 3 circles on the left top, right top and the bottom, respectively.

The first diagram represents the $U$. The second diagram represent the complement of $A
\cap B\cap C$. Etc... But what is the set operation corresponds to the last Venn diagram below?

[image]

Comment: It's the empty set. As the empty set is unique the empty set notation would do, I guess.

Comment: @KasunFernando: If you are sure why didn't post it as your answer?

Comment: It's the intersection of the 2 diagrams preceding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the first one is the 'universe' $U$, the last is $U\setminus U = \emptyset$. The blank in the pictures means that we are subtracting something from the 'universe' $U$. As an example, the second figure, the blank is $A\cap B\cap C$, and therefore the orange remaining is $U\setminus (A\cap B\cap C)$.

Answer (score 2):

Kasun Fernando says in a comment, and I agree:

> It's the empty set. As the empty set is unique the empty set notation would do, I guess.

The empty set is denoted by $\emptyset$ (`\emptyset` in $\TeX$) or $\varnothing$ (`\varnothing`).

Answer (score 0):

That is called the Ballantine operation.

[image: Ballantine Ale]

Comment: I tried to downvote this answer, but the software wouldn't let me.

Comment: Stupid software doesn't let Mark downvote his own answer!